# How do I Counter-Break combos

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

Killer instinct allows you to counter a combo-breaker by breaking the breaker (yup) to continue your combo, but to do this you must hit a certain button/perform a certain move and then your character feints and if the opponent attempts to break during the feint the counter breaker initiates.

What is the command? Does each character have a different one?

Comment: The answer is already correct but you could've learnt this by using the dojo mode in Killer Instinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing Medium Punch and Medium Kick at the same time lets you counter break combos.

[source](http://youtu.be/3tEVdKjF3tg?t=9m42s)